# Check if EditTexts for email and password are empty using firebase Toast message

Tags: java, android, firebase, validation

I am checking if the `EditText` `etEmail` and `etPass` are empty before trying to sign in, but I don't know if this is causing an issue with my toast message which uses firebase `task.getException().getMessage()`

This is the error message: Method invocation '`getMessage`' may produce `'java.lang.NullPointerException'`

I've tried taking it out of the else statement and moving it's working. I have a `SignUp.class` which works as intended with `firebase.getException().getMessage()` The `SignUp.class` does not check if the EditTexts are empty, so maybe this has something to do with the problem.

I have created a method to return true or false depending on whether the EditTexts are empty or not (passStr is the same as `etPass.getText().toString()` but inside the if statement the 2nd always returns true or always false, so I just did this to make it easier as I didn't know the best way).

```
public Boolean checkEmpty(){
    status = false;
    passStr = etPass.getText().toString();
    emailStr = etEmail.getText().toString();

   if((etPass.getText().toString().isEmpty() && etEmail.toString().isEmpty()) ||
          (passStr.isEmpty()) || (emailStr.isEmpty()) ) {
            status = false;
    }
    else{
        status = true;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Inside the onCreate method it uses

```
    if(checkEmpty().equals(true)) {


        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        etEmail.getText().toString(),
        etPass.getText().toString())
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                //this starts activity if able to sign in
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successful", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,
                                MainActivity.class));
                }
                else {
                    //if task unsuccessful it should show firebase toast messages
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                      //this getMessage does not work due to error above
                }
            }

        });
```

Then another else statement is used for when the EditTexts are empty.

```
                else {
                    progBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Please enter name and password",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is very clear. The call to `getMessage()` could be null because `task.getException()` could return null.

You should make sure the task exception is not null before calling `getMessage()`:

```java
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    ...
} else {
    Throwable taskException = task.getException();

    // Before invoking getMessage() on the exception,
    // we make sure the exception is not null
    if (taskException != null) {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, taskException.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

For your information, you should probably also check that the exception message is not null before making and showing the toast with it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent way too long and would never have worked it out otherwise. I realise I just assumed that if the task was unsuccessful it would always give getMessage(), but that is pure reliance on firebase messages.
Am I able to view what getMessages are provided? 
I would like to know more so I can see when the task is unsuccessful but has a null task exception. Thank you!

Comment: Even if there was an exception with a message for every unsuccessful task, the compiler wouldn't know about it. All the compiler knows is that `getException()` can return null sometimes, so you are always going to be forced to handle that case.

Comment: It looks like `getException()` [will never be null for unsuccessful tasks](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#getException()), so you don't have to worry about adding an `else` block.

Comment: So that confuses me. Why doesn't the else block work normally where the task is unsuccessful? But it works when you add `if (taskException != null)`. Thank you for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: I meant that you don't have to add an `else` block after `if (taskException != null)` because you can be sure that the exception of an unsuccessful task will never be null (it says so in the documentation). Thing is, the compiler has no idea about that. From the compiler's point of view, the method `getException()` could always return null, so it always forces you to handle that case with a null check.

Comment: BTW, if you think this answer solves the problem you asked about, please mark it as valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct

Try using the `try/catch()` clause

Answer (score 0):

you have to do some changes in your methods :-

this is to check edittext is empty or not:-

```
public Boolean checkEmpty(EditText edittext) {
        if (edittext.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and this is in your onCreate method:-

```
if(checkEmpty(etEmail)) {
            Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Email is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(checkEmpty(etPass)){
            Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                    etEmail.getText().toString(),
                    etPass.getText().toString())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            //this starts activity if able to sign in
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successful",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,
                                        MainActivity.class));
                            } else {
                                //if task unsuccessful it should show firebase toast messages
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //this getMessage does not work due to error above
                            }
                        }

                    });
        }
```

Comment: leave a comment if you have any query or if this answer helps you then don't forgot to appreciate the answer

Comment: hi is my answer helps you or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I have improved my code and I'm very thankful for all answers to help me understand more. 
I have got rid of the `checkEmpty()` method completely and have chosen to define each editText in my onClickListener.

```
passStr = etPass.getText().toString();
emailStr = etEmail.getText().toString();
```

which is then used in the if and else if statements

```
 if (**emailStr**.isEmpty()) 
 else if (**passStr**.isEmpty())
```

with toast messages of "please enter password" and "please enter email address".

When signUp is complete (it uses a `.addOnCompleteListener(task)` to check on `firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()`) it does this:

```
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class));
                        } else {
                            Throwable taskException = task.getException();
                            if (taskException != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
```

So, it checks if the input fields are empty first before showing firebase toast messages. I realised I was overcomplicating with the checkEmpty method as all I needed to do was define each one as strings inside the onClickListener. I didn't need to write a new method as I was not using it anywhere else.